# Translation matrix without homogeneous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking to translate a vector, and I found [this article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29), which states that I need to use homogeneous coordinates to do so.

I don't get the reason why, and I don't really see how the result of the translation matrix with homogeneous coordinates is different from a translation matrix

$$ \matrix{T} =
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & v_y & 0 \\
0 & 0 & v_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so that with my vector $\vec{p} = [p_x \, p_y \, p_z]^T$ I'd get the translation as

$$
\vec{r}=\matrix{T}\vec{p}=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x+p_x & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & v_y+p_y & 0 \\
0 & 0 & v_z+p_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the reason for using the homogeneous coordinates instead of the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, you don't really need to use homogeneous coordinates to represent translations. You can translate a point $\mathbf{p}$ by a vector $\mathbf{v}$ just by adding coordinates: $T(\mathbf{p}) = \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{v} = (p_x+v_x, p_y+v_y, p_z+v_z)$.

The benefit of using homogeneous coordinates and $4 \times 4$ matrices is that they give you a way to represent many different kinds of geometric transforms *in a uniform way*. Specifically, translations, rotations, scaling, shearing, and even central (perspective) projections can all be represented this way.

There are a couple of reasons this is valuable:

Firstly, if you need to *compose* transformations (perform several in succession, one after another), you can do this just by multiplying matrices. No special-case thinking is required. Life is tidier.

Secondly, if you're building graphics hardware, then all you need to do is create devices that can multiply $4 \times 4$ matrices, and these devices will then be able to perform a wide variety of different transformations, including all the ones that are needed in computer graphics. Hardware devices like uniformity.

Answer (score 4):

You see that, in your notation, you would get
$$
T\vec{p} =  \begin{bmatrix}\nu_x p_x \\ \nu_y p_y \\ \nu_z p_z\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a *dilation* not a *translation*.

More generally linear mappings keep the zero vector fixed, while a translation moves it. So you need a way to represent *affine* transformations.

Comment: My bad! Is it fine just to add the extra $w$ to the $\vec{p}$ and then throw it away after the translation?

Comment: Yes, something like that. See matrix representation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)